# How can I convert tab delimited data to comma delimited data?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, awk, csv

I'm requesting a list of ec2 snapshots via amazon's ec2 command line tool:

```
ec2-describe-snapshots -H --hide-tags > snapshots.csv
```

The data looks something like this:

```
SnapshotId      VolumeId        StartTime   OwnerId         VolumeSize  Description
snap-00b66464   vol-b99a38d0    2012-01-05  5098939         160         my backup
```

How can I intercept the data before redirecting it to `snapshots.csv` and do the following things:

- replace "tabs" with commas
- encapsulate values with quotations
- if a value is all numbers, prefix it with an `=` so that excel will treat it as text - for example `OwnerId` should be `"=5098939`" (this one is not necessary if it cannot be done inline and would instead require a script file or function)

desired output:

```
"SnapshotId","VolumeId","StartTime","OwnerId","VolumeSize","Description"
"snap-00b66464","vol-b99a38d0","2012-01-05","=5098939","=160","my backup"
```

Comment: This is where someone tells you to import using tabs. Or they would, if Excel wasn't on crack.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to help excel out a little bit since it doesn't seem to be doing so hot on it's own. Also having a CSV file that can just be opened instead of having to use the import menu command is always nice. I already tried changing the extension to ".tsv" with no luck.

Comment: I think your desired output is a bit off. You have a lot of empty fields in there (the empty quotes).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS = "\t"; OFS = "," }
{
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        if ($i + 0 == $i) { $i = "=" $i }
        else gsub(/"/, "\"\"", $i);
        $i = "\"" $i "\""
    }
    print
}
```

Assuming you name this `convert.awk`, you can either call with either

```
ec2-describe-snapshots -H --hide-tags | awk -f convert.awk > snapshots.csv
```

or (after adding execute permissions, `chmod a+x convert.awk`)

```
ec2-describe-snapshots -H --hide-tags | ./convert.awk > snapshots.csv
```

This will make a new column for each 
tab, which will keep the comment column together (unless it contains tabs), but add empty columns (though that is how your sample output looks, so maybe you actually do want that).
If you want to split on all whitespace (this will collapse extra tabs within the table but put each word in the description as a new column), take out the `FS="\t";` statement.

For future generations, if you don't need the `"`s or `=`s or embedded whitespace, you can make it a one-liner:

```
awk -v OFS=, '{$1=$1;print}'
```

Comment: Nice clean solution. Thought it would end up a lot uglier than that, but then I'm not a awk person :-)

Comment: so do i save this into a file such as `./convert.sh`, chmod +x, and then pipe the input into it so that it will print the output? I'm getting an error: `/usr/bin/awk: syntax error at source line 1 context is >>> . <<< /convert.sh`.

Comment: @cwd You can save it in a file, I'd suggest `convert.awk` to indicate it's an `awk` script and not a `bash` one.  I updated the post  with the full command line, and note that I added a `-f` flag I had forgotten to the first line (that tells it to interpret the file as commands).

Comment: The one-liner version treats any whitespace as a field separator, not just tabs. Needs a -F'\t' before the -V.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a perl solution. This might be possible with sed/awk, but testing for the numeric part would likely make it pretty ugly.

```
ec2-describe-snapshots -H --hide-tags | \
perl -e 'use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);
         while (chomp($line = <STDIN>)) {
             print(join(",", map { "\"" . (looks_like_number($_) ? "=$_" :
                                           do {s/"/""/g; $_}) . "\"" }
             split(/\t/, $line)) . "\n");
         }' \
> snapshots.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're just lazy like me and want to do it all on one command line without writing a script, here's how i'd do it.

```
ec2-describe-snapshots -H --hide-tags | sed -e 's/^I/","/g' | sed -e 's/^/"/' | sed -e 's/$/"/'> snapshots.csv
```

The `^I` is made by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd>.

The first `sed` swaps all the `tabs` for `","`.  The second `sed` inserts a `"` at the beginning of each line, and the last sed inserts a closing `"` at the end of each line.

Comment: How did you get the ctrl + v i to show up like that?

Comment: @burhan The syntax is `<kbd>text</kbd>`.

Comment: Or in one line: `sed -e 's/^I/","/g' -e 's/.*/"&"/'` or even shorter `sed -e 's/^I/","/g;s/.*/"&"/'`.

Answer (score 3):

Another Perl solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wln
use strict;

my($n,$s);chomp();
for $s ( split(/\t/,$_) )
{
    $s = '='.$s if ($s =~ /^\d+$/);
    $n.= '"'.$s.'",';
}
$n =~ s/(.*),/$1/;print $n;
```

invoke with  `ec2-describe-snapshots -H --hide-tags | /var/tmp/script.pl > output.txt`

Comment: Scalar::Util isnt an outside module, it comes with standard perl.

Comment: True. Apologies for poorly wording my intended comment. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

sed is the most useful linux utility I have ever encountered.

```
sed 's/\t/","/g' TabSeparatedValues.txt > CommaSeparatedValues.csv
sed -i 's/.*/"&"/' CommaSeparatedValues.csv
```

The first command replaces all tabs in every line with commas and quotes. The second command inserts quotes at the beginning and end of each line, so that each values will be surrounded in quotes, which allows commas to be part of the value.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/\t\+/,/g;s/^\|$/"/g;s/,/"&"/g;s/"\([0-9]\+\)"/"=\1"/g' file
```